# MVC Model, inherit Validation Attributes from another Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

As a follow on from my previous question ([MVC abstract ViewModel, retain Validation Attributes (dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071282/mvc-abstract-viewmodel-retain-validation-attributes-dynamically)) I thought I'd ask the question in an alternate version.

So, let's consider the same situation, where I have a core ViewModel:

```
public class SampleViewModel {
    [Required]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public IList<AnotherModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And another model:

```
public AnotherModel {
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then within a controller, I perform the following:

```
var model = new SampleViewModel();
var fields = new List<AnotherModel>() {
    new AnotherModel() { Value = model.Property1 },
    new AnotherModel() { Value = model.Property2 },
};
```

So, my question is, how can I get the AnotherModel models to respond to the properties that are passed to their respective Value property.

In the sample above, the first AnotherModel will be **Required**, and the second will be **Required**, and an **EmailAddress**.

How is this possible?

Thank you

### Update

For the purpose of this, lets say that each of those AnotherModel objects is represented by a form field. When the form is posted back, I use a custom model binder to obtain the Value from the AnotherModel and place it back into the source property (so Property1). My model is reconstructed correctly, and ModelState.IsValid is working. So, I have server-side validation of my SampleViewModel on post-back. Can this be somehow passed to the client to validate for me, based on the model's validation attributes?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer - you can't. You should ether add attributes on `AnotherModel` property and have 2 models for each case or inherit your `AnotherModel` from `SampleViewModel` so you will had same property names in your `AnotherModel` as you have `SampleViewModel`.

Comment: Not quite the answer I was hoping for teo van kot. Perhaps I'm missing something then. Is there a way that I can validate my AnotherModels based on attributes from another model?

Comment: `AnotherModel` is just a class. The compiler doesn't know or care that it's similar to `SampleViewModel` and certainly doesn't know or care that you want it to be treated in the same way as `SampleViewModel`. Add the same validation attributes or inherit.

Comment: @Oxonhammer nope. I mean there is. But for your case - 1 model, 2 different rules - definatly there is no

Comment: To pick up on teo's first comment, can I pass in some validation instructions into each model (required, type, length, etc) and then have each model validate itself based on this data?

Comment: I could try to obtain all ValidationAttributes from the property, and use these to create the ValidationRules for each model? I could then implement IValidatableObject on the AnotherModel to have this decide its state?